# conditional expectation of gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-expectation

Let $(X_1, \ldots , X_n)$ be a gaussian random vector with zero mean and covariance matrix $B$.  Find the distribution of the random vector $E(X_1 \mid X_2, \ldots, X_n)$.  I am not sure how to proceed.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find formulas for the [conditional distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) from a Gaussian vector.

In particular, if $B=\begin{bmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12} \\ B_{12}^\top & B_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ where $B_{11}$ is $1 \times 1$ and $B_{22}$ is $(n-1) \times (n-1)$, then the conditional expectation is
$$E[X_1 \mid X_2 ,\ldots, X_n] = B_{12} B_{22}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}X_2 \\ X_2 \\ \vdots \\ X_n \end{bmatrix}.$$

This is a linear transformation of the Gaussian vector $(X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ to a univariate random variable, so the distribution is univariate Gaussian. I'll leave it to you to compute the mean and variance of this univariate Gaussian.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then this is not what the original post is asking. The original question asks for the distribution of the conditional expectation (which we know is a random variable).

Comment: @AdityaGuhaRoy My last paragraph uses the expression for the conditional expectation to reason that the distribution of the conditional expectation is univariate Gaussian. It remains to compute the mean and variance, which I've left as an exercise to OP.

Comment: Ahh yes! There is this regression point of view which makes this formula quite natural. I was trying to derive it from scratch by analysing the mean square minimiser, and even that works but it requires a lot more steps than this; also computation of mean and variance would be difficult in that way in comparison to what you have answered.